# Finding private key in RSA

Tags: key, rsa, private

I've been trying to figure out how to find the private key in the RSA equation with no luck.
Given

```
 p = 31
 q = 23
 e = 223
 phi = (p-1)(q-1)
      = 660
```

The equation (d*e mod phi = 1) results in;

```
e mod phi = 1/d
```

so

```
 223 mod 660 = 1/d
 223 = 1/d
 1/223 = d
```

but in this example they get d = 367, which I can't get. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: phil is very productive. Or at least multiplicative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calculating d is not that simple. You can use the extended Euclidean algorithm to solve for d.

```
d=1/e mod phi
```

[For RSA, how do i calculate the secret exponent?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3209665/1232571)