# rsa calculations

Tags: encryption, rsa

I am trying to solve RSA for 2 small numbers. I can calculate n,phi and e but I always get stuck when I have to calculate d. Please help me with the same.
example.

```
        p = 3,      q = 7,
        n =  3*7 = 21,
        phi(21)= 2*6 = 12, 
        e = 5

        d = (5^-1) (mod 21) 

        or

        d * 5 = k * 12 + 1   (where k is some number)
```

I tried to figure out the calculation of d * 5 = 25 = 5 * 12 + 1 but this is for small number is there any other way to calculate d with simple approach

Comment: what language are you using? What are you trying to do in your calculation of `d`? `(5^-1)` could be bit manipulation, to-the-power-of-'-1', ...

Comment: "Please show some detail example" is what makes this question highly unsuited for Stack Overflow.

Comment: iirc, `(5^-1) (mod 21)` in this context means the inverse of 5 mod 21.

Comment: Just started using Stack Overflow.. I beg ur pardon if I made some mistake

Comment: its true i meant inverse of 5 mod 21

Comment: The reason your question is unsuitable here is because you've done the (very) easy calculations yourself and asked for us to do the difficult one for you, without showing that you've tried to figure it out yourself, or even that you've looked up how to do it.

Comment: If you show that you've put forth real effort, we are much more inclined to help you.

Comment: do u want me to show wrong calculations which i done for d?

Comment: Sure. You might even see what went wrong and get the answer yourself.

Comment: You could look at [this earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209665/for-rsa-how-do-i-calculate-the-secret-exponent)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following pseudo code may help you (with heavy borrowing from [this link](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/%7Emitra/honors/soln.html)

```
// choose prime factors:
p = 3;
q = 7;

n = p * q; // =21
phi = (p-1)*(q-1); // = 12
// Choose e such that 1 < e < phi and e and n are coprime:
e = 5; 
// Compute a value for d such that (d * e) % phi = 1. 
// in other words, solve 5 * d % 12 = 1
d = 5; // since 5 * 5 = 25; modulo 12 = 1. How odd: d == e...

Public key is (e, n) => (5, 21) 
Private key is (d, n) => (5, 21) 

Testing this out on a "message" with the value of '2':
The encryption of m = 2 is 
    c = 2^5 % 21 = 32 % 21 = 11 
The decryption of c = 11 is 
    m = 11^5 % 21 = 161051 % 21 = 2
```

As you can see, we got the "message" back after the encryption / decryption step.

Note that since e==d, this is (unfortunately) a symmetric cypher: if you apply the encryption again, you get back the message as well. This shows that the choice of e was poor. That's a problem with these toy RSA problems...

Comment: ok thanks for the help... also plz check the following

Comment: @Kunj - "plz check the following"??? What do you mean?

Comment: ok thanks for the help... also plz check the following
 m = c^d mod 77
 m = 10^37 mod 77
 m = (67*67*67*7) mod 77
 m = 7 ??? is this correct ?

Comment: You might find [this calculator](https://www.cs.drexel.edu/~jpopyack/IntroCS/HW/RSAWorksheet.html) instructive. How did `10^37 mod 77` turn into `(67*67*67*7)mod 77`? You can use Wolfram Alpha's `PowerMod` [function](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PowerMod%5B10%2C37%2C77%5D) -which gives `10` as the answer.